# Laravel: Selective drop down lists

Tags: laravel

So my drop down list works that I HAVE to select both options for it to display a list of hotels based on the criteria selected (Distance and price), but I want to make sure that the user can find all hotels based on just Price, for example. When I do this, no hotels appear and my drop down list doesn't quite work. So how would I exactly implement code that will let the user select all the hotels based on just the ONE criteria.

SearchController.php

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $distances = DB::table('posts')->select('distance')->distinct()->get()->pluck('distance');
    $prices = DB::table('posts')->select('price')->distinct()->get()->pluck('price');

    $post = Post::query();

    if ($request->has('price')) {
        $post->where('price', $request->price);
    }

    if ($request->has('distance')) {
        $post->where('distance', $request->distance);
    }

    return view('Pages.search', [
        'distances' => $distances,
        'prices' => $prices,
        'posts' => $post->get(),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `when`?

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // Unnecessary select * changed to select only the columns you need.
    $distances = DB::table('posts')->select('distance')->distinct()->get(['distance'])->pluck('distance');
    $prices = DB::table('posts')->select('price')->distinct()->get(['price'])->pluck('price');

    $post = Post::when($request->has('price'), function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('price', $request->price);
    })
    ->when($request->has('distance'), function ($query) use ($request) {{
        $query->where('distance', $request->distance);
    })
    ->get();

    /* php  >= 7.4
    $post = Post::when($request->has('price'), fn($query) => $query->where('price', $request->price))
    ->when($request->has('distance'), fn($query) => $query->where('distance', $request->distance))
    ->get();
    */

    return view('Pages.search', compact('distances', 'prices', 'post');
}
```

Comment: Before implementing this to see if it may work, what exactly does the when statement do ?

Comment: okay so i implemented the where statement and i am receiving the same issue as previous

Comment: the when statement adds to the query depending on the first parameter. This issue you have is because the query throws an error or because it doesn't return any results? If it's the later, are you sure there is a post with the required filter?

Comment: Yeah so the functionality of it works as it does return the results i want. HOWEVER if the user wants hotels based on just price the outcome is nothing as no results are actually posted. This also applies when i select the distance.

Comment: Can you place `DB::enableQueryLog();` before `$posts` and then `dd(DB::getQueryLogs());` after the `->get();`? This will dump the sql query that was executed. Check if everything is in order.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of the use of 'has' i simply implemented the 'filled' and this ensured that my filtering worked.